# Nunit locks while is running a test suite

Tags: selenium, locking, nunit, block

I have an issue when I try to run a test suite in NUnit. It locks while is running the tests and then displays this error message. I used the lastest version of NUnit and I wrote this tests using c#, Visual Studio 2010 and Selenium Client Drivers 2.12.

Any idea?.

### **ERROR DETAIL:**

See the end of this message for details on invoking

just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4829



    Server stack trace:



   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint ipEndPoint)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket()

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)



Exception rethrown at [0]: 

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.get_Running()

   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.get_Running()

   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.get_Running()

   at NUnit.Gui.NUnitForm.get_IsTestRunning()

   at NUnit.Gui.NUnitForm.NUnitForm_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

************** Loaded Assemblies **************

mscorlib

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3625 (GDR.050727-3600)

CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
```

---

nunit

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/nunit.exe
```

---

nunit-gui-runner

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit-gui-runner.DLL
```

---

nunit.core

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.DLL
```

---

nunit.util

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.util.DLL
```

---

nunit.uikit

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.uikit.DLL
```

---

System.Windows.Forms

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3623 (GDR.050727-3600)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

---

System

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3624 (GDR.050727-3600)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
```

---

System.Drawing

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
```

---

nunit.core.interfaces

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.core.interfaces.DLL
```

---

System.Configuration

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
```

---

System.Xml

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
```

---

System.Runtime.Remoting

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
```

---

nunit.uiexception

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.5.10.11092

CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/NUnit%202.5.10/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit.uiexception.DLL
```

---

System.Web

```
Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3618 (GDR.050727-3600)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
```

---

cdqzko4t

```
Assembly Version: 2.5.10.11092

Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3624 (GDR.050727-3600)

CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
```

---

************** JIT Debugging **************

To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this

application or computer (machine.config) must have the

jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.

The application must also be compiled with debugging

enabled.

For example:

```
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
```

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception

will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer

rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: What test? It's says the socket connection was actively refused. Firewall, not listening, not listening on that port....

Comment: Is a common test in an application that running on IE6. This test gets data from the data base and does some managements on the system.

Comment: Sort out why it can't connect is what I was saying, all else is a buit pointelss until you've addressed that.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced that same exception and I found a number of threads about it. There was [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/881958), which might produce the issue in your case.

In my case I use NUnit version 2.6.0.1205, where the bug was already fixed. So my case is different from the one described in the bug. 
The problem was, because I changed output application type and target framework from *Console Application* and *.NET Framework 4 Client Profile* to *Class library* and *.NET Framework 4*.

The solution was to change them back to *Console application* and *.NET Framework 4 Client Profile*.

It is not the exact answer to the question, but I hope it will help to those ones who meet the same problem.

**Update:** Another case for this exception is when one of the test terminates the process. For example, it can happen if the test calls a C/C++ function from another DLL, which calls `exit`.

Comment: "Another case for this exception is when one of the test terminates the process." Yep, for me something like this occured when a test allocated a Console windows by calling some kernel functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I managed to fix it by creating a new NUnit project and by reloading the assembly.